# KML Icons coloring

Tags: colors, icons, kml

I have a KML  map with 3 different icons: red, blue and mixed. lately the icons in the map lost their red coloring.  any idea what happened?
https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=he&geocode=&q=http://www.coal-ash.co.il/maps/coalash_map_kml/more_5000

The index on the right reflects the right shape and color.

Answer (score 0):

You've explicitly specified the colour for each style via the `<color>` tags:

```xml
<IconStyle>
    <color>ff8c4800</color>
    <Icon>
        <href>http://www.coal-ash.co.il/maps/sites/all/modules/coalash/icons/red.png</href>
    </Icon>
</IconStyle>
```

This colour is applied as an overlay to your PNG icons. For example, if you use a neutral colour like `AAAAAA00`, you'll see that your icon will still be visible, but darkened.

Just remove the color tag, and your png icons will render correctly.